# will this have any side effect?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I wanted to pass PHP variables to Javascript without triggering any new http request (aka: inserting it directly in markup). But I wanted the content **as is** (without any sanitization that could change my values, even if they where markup itself). Of course I wanted to keep it safe as well.

The best way i've came up so far includes json + base64_encode + data uri schemes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data:text/javascript;base64,<?php echo base64_encode('var thing = '.json_encode($thing)); ?>"></script>
```

**My question is**: will this have any side effect? can I safely use this?

Comment: One thing is it won't work in IE 7 and 8, probably not even 9. And then I can't really see the point of this exercise? What does this achieve that simply inserting the plain text JavaScript doesn't?

Comment: I have done something very similar (JSON/base64), in my case it was for sending complex data client->server with a single URL parameter. It worked fine.

Comment: But yeah in your case, if you JSON encode the string you ought to be able to drop that directly into the markup, it won't need encoding or escaping (the JSON encoding effectively escapes any strings for you).

Comment: Please do not put an answer into the question.

Comment: @Martin, sorry. Anyone has a workaround for this? i was thinking of using `base64.js` to do the decoding afterwards (but obviously it would be an overhead)...

Comment: @hugo_leonardo: Answer Pekka's question first

Comment: @Pekka I had some trouble inserting json data that included html markup and i didn't want to change it with htmlspecialchars or similar...

Comment: What kind of sanitization would affect a php `echo`? Why not simply go `<script type="text/javascript">var thing=<?php echo json_encode($thing); ?>;</script>`?

Comment: @hugo base64 encoding will not fix that problem. The only reason for the problem that I can think of is charset issues, and base64 encoding will not remedy them.   Best ask a question about the trouble you're getting, and show the relevant code

Comment: +1 to Pekka. A simple echo as shown above should work in all cases.

Comment: @Pekka Oh i see it now, i was doing a mess with `json_encode()` wrapped in quotes and `JSON.parse()`. I didn't realize that json was an object literal itself and needed no decoding in js :p // by the way, post your answer so i can accept it. thank you very much (:

Comment: @hugo no problem. Accept Josh's answer, he already said pretty much what I would have said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I certainly wouldn't do this.  You're introducing unnecessary compatibility problems (IE).  By base64 encoding, you're bloating the size of your JSON by [~37%](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#MIME).

```
<script type="text/javascript">var thing = <?php echo json_encode($thing); ?></script>
```

<s>Realistically, the only problem you might run in to is if `$thing` has a '`</script>`' in a string somewhere.</s> *(It looks like `json_encode()` actually escapes all forward slashes `/`, so this isn't a problem.)*  HTML parsers will ignore anything else that might look like markup in a `<script>` block.

You do have to watch out for text encoding if your page isn't UTF-8.

Comment: +1,  but for completeness' sake, another problem one might run into is outputting JSON (which is always UTF-8) in a ISO-8859-1 or other non-UTF-8 context.

Comment: actually i tested @Pekka's solution with an array containing a `</script>` string and it worked just fine.

Comment: @hugo_leonardo: In what browser?  Chrome 18, Firefox 9, IE 9, and Opera 11.52 all stopped processing `<script>var str='blah</script>'; alert('ok');</script>` on the first `</script>`, and `'; alert('ok');` showed up as text in the document.  (Plus a `SyntaxError` for the mis-parsed script.)  **Edit:** The escaping would explain why it worked.